# django mongoengine unable to login using correct password

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I am using `mongoengine` with `django rest framework` and default User model：

#### settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'

MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'
```

#### views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout

from mongoengine.django.auth import User

@csrf_exempt
def log_in(request):    
    js = json.loads(request.body)
    try:
        #user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
        user = User.objects.get(username=js['username'])
        print user.username
        print user.password
        print js['username']
        print js['password']
        print user.password==js['password']
        #if user.check_password(request.POST['password']):
        if user.check_password(js['password']):
            user.backend = 'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'
            user = authenticate(username=js['username'], password=js['password'])
            login(request, user)
            request.session.set_expiry(60 * 60 * 1) # 1 hour timeout
            return HttpResponse(user)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('login failed')
    except DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse('user does not exist')
    except Exception:
        return HttpResponse('unknown error')
```

With the correct password, I am getting login failed. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you add the User model or its `check_password` method, as it seems like the method is throwing a negation due to which your `if`fails

Comment: I managed to get it going now, I had to use set_password for adding the password. Now I am able to authenticate, but I cannot login. I need to know what exactly goes in the request(which is passed as an argument in login)